# EXCEL VBA Use msgbox to show items in combobox

Tags: excel, vba

## First: When initialize the userform

I initialize my page by using code below so that it will populate my combobox.

```
For Each cell In rangeA
    If cell.Value <> "" Then
        ComboBox1.AddItem cell.Value
    Else
    End If
Next
```

## Next

I have a button to prompt a msgbox that will call all the items inside my combobox. How do I do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you just store them as you add them from the range?

Comment: What do you mean by 'call the the items?'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done as follows:

```
Private Sub ShowComboBoxAsMsgBox()
    Dim s As String
    Dim sep As String
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 0 To Me.ComboBox1.ListCount - 1
        s = s & sep & Me.ComboBox1.List(i)
        sep = vbCrLf
    Next i

    MsgBox s, vbInformation, "my ComboBox"
End Sub
```